# Call service inside require.config paths

Tags: angularjs, service, requirejs, require, referenceerror

Is it possible to get your path from a service? because i have the following error:

```
cause: ReferenceError: serviceFactory is not defined
```

this is what i try to do:

```
require.config
          paths:
            vScript:
              do ->
                service = serviceFactory.getService()
                if !service
                  throw new Error 'not configured.'
                url = service.getScriptUrl()
                return url = 'https://test.com/js/test.1.min'
          shim:
            vScript:
              exports: 'v'

        require ['vScript'], ->
          _alreadyLoaded = true
```

Comment: You need to inject `serviceFactory`before you use it

Comment: @ShashankVivek inject into require or ...  just in my file?

Comment: I havent work with `require` but yes it should be **injected into the function** where it is being called. The error u are getting is becaz your code is not able to figure out what `serviceFactory` is.